# How can I get chromedriver process PID using Java?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've faced a problem. Sometimes, while my JUnit tests are running, command webDriver.quit(); isn't killing chromedriver process so the next test can't start. In that case I want to add some method which may kill process manually on Linux, but I can't figure out how to get PID of chromedriver so I can do something like: 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + PID);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find PIDs using pgrep and then kill it:

```
    private void killChromedriver() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command = "pgrep chromedriver";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        List<String> processIds = getProcessedIds (process, br);
        for (String pid: processIds) {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + pid);
                p.waitFor();
                p.destroy();
        }
    }
    private List<String> getProcessedIds(Process process, BufferedReader br) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        process.waitFor();

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String processId ;

        while (null != (processId = br.readLine())) {
            result.add(processId);
        }

        process.destroy();
        return result;
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Another and more simple solution seems to be

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill chromedriver");
```

Comment: Can't get it, what is in "getProcessedIds (process, br);" method? It's undefined.

Comment: By the way it seems possible to just use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + PID);

Comment: Sorry, Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill chromedriver");

Comment: This only works if you're only ever running one chromedriver instance on the machine