# python - How to prevent chromedriver.exe from closing the socket connection on a Interrupt Signal?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, interrupt-handling

I'm using selenium in my python script for interacting with web pages. The 
script runs on Cygwin. The script looks like this on a high level:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    browser.quit()
    #close other things
    sys.exit()

def browser_function():
    #do something with browser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    browser_function()
    browser.quit()
```

There are two different things happening here on a) normal exit and  b) exit by interruption. On a normal exit, `browser.quit()` works perfectly and closes both driver (chromedriver.exe) and browser (chrome.exe) processes. However, when it exits through `signal_handler()`, only driver processes are closed. I can see many of "chrome.exe" processes running in cmd.

If I use `browser.close()`(which is supposed to only close the chrome windows) inside `signal_handler()`, it raises a socket.error exception stating `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`. So I'm assuming Ctrl+C signal will reset the socket connection to the browser.

What I want is to prevent this connection reset from happening so that I can cleanly quit the browser.

I dont want use `taskkill /im "chrome.exe"` in cmd as it also kills running browser sessions opened by user. So How to,
1) Prevent the interrupt signal from closing the socket connection? or,
2) Find the pids of "chrome.exe" processes that were opened by chromedriver and not the user?

Comment: here is in java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467793/how-can-i-get-chromedriver-process-pid-using-java it may helps you

Comment: thanks. will look into it